# Dart/Flutter Datetime isBefore() function not acting correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

In my Dart Flutter project I have this simple code:

```
print("API UTC time $localUTC");
print("Now UTC time: $nowUtc");
print(localUTC.isBefore(nowUtc));
```

Which has this output:

```
I/flutter ( 1605): API UTC time 2023-12-31 00:00:00.000
I/flutter ( 1605): Now UTC time: 2023-12-31 00:06:21.658634Z
I/flutter ( 1605): false
```

I would expect the output to be true, not false based on this. What I think is happening is that the Datetime I get from my API call is slightly different format then what I am getting from:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime nowUtc = now.toUtc();
```

When I query the system using the `now()` function and convert it to UTC. It looks like I have milliseconds and Z for zulu added at the end. I think the format being slightly off is breaking the `localUTC.isBefore(nowUtc)` call.

Any suggestion on how to approach this issue?

Comment: `localUTC` is clearly is a local time and is *not* UTC (the variable name is self-contradictory).

Answer (score 1):

After som more troubleshooting I was able to solve my issue by just adding the letter "Z" to the end of my API UTC time:

```
  apiUTC = DateTime.parse(hourlyData[i].timestampUTC + "Z");
```